# minimum number of slice required to make strings equal

Tags: java, string, algorithm, function, lcs

Can somebody please help me out with this problem?

what is the minimum number of slices required to make string A equal to string b?

Example:

```
String A = "gamergirls"
String B = "merils"
```

ga **| **mer** |** g **| **i** |** r **| ls**  -> 5 slices to make merils.

Constraints :

- characters in both the strings are lowercase.
- A.length && B.length <= 10^5

Comment: Please help me I am not able to find what should be the right approach to attempt this problem.

Comment: Have a look at the Smith-Waterman algorithm. Although it's use is mainly in DNA sequence alignment, what you want here is to find the minimum number of inserts needed.

Comment: I didn't understand Smith-Waterman algorithm. I'm a high school student. try to keep it simple. @user1717259

Comment: Did you make this problem up or do you have any online link where we could test our solution?

Comment: yes, it just came to my mind while solving Longest common substring problem. I don't have any such link

Comment: Ok, your constraints are too tight to come up with an efficient one. Brute force was to check for every substring in A and figure out the slices required and get the minimum out of them.

Comment: Dynamic programming could be of help to cache the cuts required for a substring to improve time complexity.

Comment: I set the constraints myself if you think finding an efficient solution is difficult with these given constraints. you are free to change it. I just need an explanation to do this problem

Comment: @rustytheron With the solution I can think of, time complexity could get too high. So your string lengths could barely be more than 10-15 for it. Not sure if it would be relevant to you.

Comment: the problem presented here might actually fit nicely as a https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ exercise.

Comment: @rustytheron Can we make answer for your sample case as `6`? It is pretty confusing what you mean by a slice? Can we reframe the word as splits?

Answer (score 1):

- As mentioned by you in the comments for the constraints, I am proposing a **O(<sup>An</sup>C<sub>Bn</sub>)** solution where `An` is the length of the string `A` and `Bn` is the length of the string `B`.
- Space complexity would be `O(An)` where `An` is the length of the string `A`.

---

**Algorithm:**

- We first make simple checks with lengths of `A` and `B`. If `B` is longer, then return `-1`.  If both have same lengths, if they are same, return `0`, else `-1`.
- For `A.length()` > `B.length()`,

  - We check for every possible subsequence with length of `A` with length of `B` number of 1's in it. For your example, the `bits` array as in my below code would initially look like,

    ```
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
    ```
  - This `bits` array basically means we are going to check *for every* possible permutation of it including the above one to see if any subsequence of `A` matches this. The `1` bit should match with corresponding character in `B`, else it is a failed permutation.
  - If any permutation of `bits` matches, we count the no. of cuts required to make it a success. For your example, the permutation of `bits` array would look like below,

    ```
    0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
    -------------------
    g a m e r g i r l s
    ```
  - As you can see above, we have 6 segments of `0`s and `1`s. In the end, we just take minimum of all of the possibilities and return it.

**Main Code:**

```
int min_cuts = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
do{
    int ptr = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<bits.length && ptr < B.length();++i){
        if(bits[i] == '1'){
            if(A.charAt(i) == B.charAt(ptr)){
                ptr++;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(ptr == B.length()){
        min_cuts = Math.min(min_cuts, getCuts(bits) - 1);
    }
}while(nextPermutation(bits));
```

[**Complete Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3xnqbr62g)

Comment: Thanks for the help @nice_dev. I appreciate your efforts. Thanks